No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one at useQueryClien Error in using reactQueryProvider
I am using react-router@6 and react-query@5.
I take this error message when I want log the States data: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one at useQueryClient.how can I that fix. please guid me.
enter image description here
this is my code:
enter image description here
enter image description here

You could not have useStates on the same layer you returned <QueryClientProvider/>
Try removing the layer and rewrap the contents like so
App.tsx
...
    return (
         <>
         <ReactQueryDevTools ... />
         <RouteProvider ... />
         </>
    )


Root.tsx
...
   return (
        <QueryClientProvider>
        <App />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    )

